# is it possible to make lzw compression/decompression parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, compression, lzw

i have read [this article](http://marknelson.us/2011/11/08/lzw-revisited/) on how to compress/decompress data using LZW but i'm looking to make it use multiple threads... but i think it is not possible. what do you think? any papers or articles on this subject? or even hints on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read [this paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271602/1-s2.0-S0166218X04X00226/1-s2.0-S0166218X04003476/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECAaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIHB3sqX42jm4xXikWIXucw5gbdAg3fnUOmVQziEH4oBCAiEA4GL8lEUPpg%2Fno3bkcS3oXDNNB5I9SZt41oVP56hzVA0qswUISBAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDBbaaeWzAWYBP%2F8LgiqQBSqxLwgR%2FyirA20paZGOG5CELnICqO%2F4Ro%2Bf4V%2B1VjyFIl1Rt7RCNp3wEDIKK6UcGqruUos8RcRfmh50Dygv7254kf4U1LQ8nz8cz%2FMU1e9%2F6EjaaA2v4YNYdm8X%2BuspOZzpSAcqHYpPeaWwoHc95hMRQsvakGaiHDTtVKtKmDl0mCStr1KPaUTZCHDBI62Add%2Fm4QWofEi47qafqH3zxmnMMHgosqYiyhJRu%2FMOyCZryc3QWUmARFzh53CxyJ65TOtOfO4CxUlE6S4Uw4hwEwqgnirt9SCDDfjrv0Wan8LmcQuOlk%2BNienpBmPSnkC21zT0LSyZEWu71vCQXz00X4N5kf6xRX7fXbffyYiR7OOUIGZE%2B%2BBN7g3cLs59hW1ff0qA0LLfOp9tKQRUYR%2Bw1lPn5b3D%2FY%2Bl%2B3Z7U7F%2FtKgTLIfdqQF7pAN%2F3ev5BQRVwPDxbuCkCi9op0eTQLY9ojR1iqCJDLDpess31JqjZDy3FOcn9Uhci1033qco%2BIiQY3fOwNOSUA7hk6WE8C7QDaoj64soDPtLPGO5NLcW1%2FPF4tEC62W9McM38oYRawzIdvS9Xfz7xtnQwkdyP9e5na96XpBcJUX9kO5mn09MUFrQMvzMNjQHg1NoU31UdtQlydOczSqXaZjwVAlwkw7xrZr9AEdzwdh1BYec%2BAee7ZCzNpOjTeotx%2FkzEqPYrv4PTp3Kc5r07%2BPqHHIiRX57bQkJdapqM7Z72mlDBj49d10Rrp2vrf4Hiudn7QNODO25zjj0C9CMZox0KnosY2JgVuZpVevr0uEl93WTFl%2FWAY3AY4lkQtTtI7aQrhYKoUZtBeqNpdW5S169NO61stYwlE%2FdP0fiVhFCsWL3Gi0OyvnJMNq836kGOrEBtjWjIkGfJ%2Fp8LDh5URl8FP4KNd8APPqXtO3opzZpXya%2BVPJz5p1%2FgTx2iNjPl5mqKmkIOfisUwS72aDYmlp1XMfxK1l3HmvwvXOPqapqNo2oJ2EhTTMgonKijMryeZlA3XFNztOOVwiLySNlMG58wPBHpiMV7Z%2BtL%2FgEbbDYFuwLkfCCvf5593LTmL4wVGxMJR76m6cOBrvUk5Ay%2Bm1poU7osT%2BYPdKElpr1JFQopOge&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231024T153914Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY7QAHIKTX%2F20231024%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=5b57e2f809d5d97ee64d1d61596249edb4a41954d8246df831848a86a04bdcff&hash=6d50f2ead29e1838c7ce86d6030a685b51454d989c440fc040e9f2e2b9073e4b&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0166218X04003476&tid=spdf-3d8211a2-63e4-4287-bbc2-73415ea4f2a9&sid=c2eb20dc7ccb0248735ae712be6e382203bbgxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=13145856025d5a04045d&rr=81b34fb3cc474bef&cc=it), in particular Section 2.2 explains exactly how to parallelize a LZW scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Parallelizing a compression algorithm at a low level will provide limited speedup and is likely to be more trouble than it's worth.  The reason is that the real benefit would be in compressing large sets of data.  In that case, it is far easier to simply break up the data into pieces and compress them individually with the normal algorithm.

LZW is old and not very effective.  Other methods can compress faster and more effectively.  You can look at various schemes from [lz4](http://code.google.com/p/lz4/) to [zlib](http://zlib.net/) to [lzma](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) to ppmd, paq, etc., in a sequence from fastest with least compression to slowest with best compression.  An example of parallelization is [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/), which uses [zlib](http://zlib.net/) to compress large files to the [gzip format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) using as many processors and cores as you have.  It provides history from previous blocks to subsequent blocks in a parallel manner, so as to not lose compression effectiveness as compared to a serial, one-processor gzip compression.

Answer (score 0):

Parallelization of compression or decompression algorithm using multiple threads is reasonable when there are a lot of integer arithmetic to do. But `lzw` doesn't require it. You can see [lzws](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/lzws/tree/master/src/compressor) source for example.

The amount of integer arithmetic is low. The main bottleneck is `dictionary`. You can receive more performance using memory overclocking and custom malloc realloc strategies.